# Multiple equations given the same number

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

Without doing anything "odd" LaTeX has starting assigning the same number to different equations. It labels them fine up until 31, then it goes back to 30, then again 31, then again 31. After this it seems to go back to numbering sequentially. A couple of the equations are even given the \label{name} with different names, but LaTeX is still giving them the same number in the output.

I've been using LaTeX for years and have not seen this before. Like I said I didn't do anything differently this time than I have a hundred others.

I get no errors in the build output.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us to help you and add [a minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: Without a lot more, and more detailed, information about your document setup, it's not going to be possible to offer a useful diagnosis, let alone a fix. Which TeX distribution do you use? Did you recently switch document classes? Which commands do you use to generate displayed equations? Ideally, you should be providing an MWE that generates the problem behavior you wish to fix.

Comment: For document class I've got \documentclass[twocolumn,showpacs,preprintnumbers,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4} And I'm using the graphicx, dcolumn, bm packages. I basically use this exact same preamble to every document I write with little (usually no) variation. I use the eqnarray environment for most equations and flalign for a couple others. I use miktex with the TeXnicCenter editor. Like I said, I've used this same stuff dozens or more times without this happening, so short of posting my whole document I don't think doing a "MWE" will do any good...

Comment: Please provide an entire latex file that shows the behavior you describe.  Without it, there's little hope of getting an answer since it's hard for everyone else to figure out what's going on.

Comment: You need to make an small example that demonstrates the problem. start from a copy of your document. If you have equations 30,31,30, delete everything after that point. Now delete everything before equation 30, do you get equations 1,2,1? If not, put things back a bit at a time until the problem occurs.